# interesting pandas loc behavior

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I've attached a screenshot of a pd.DataFrame I am using and I've observed some interesting behavior within loc that to me is counter-intuitive / doesn't make much sense to me, as after reading the pandas API I would have thought are equivalent (at just for example quicker than loc).

Effectively, in a two-dimensional dataframe I thought these methods should be equivalent, but they come up with different results:

Method 1

```
df.loc[label, column]
```

Method 2

```
df.at[label, column]
```

Method 3

```
df[column].loc[label]
```

[image: Code snippit]

Out[77] depicts the structure of the table, and what I find interesting is how the output method df.loc[label, column] for label '3T19' and column 'wing1' outputs results that (I don't understand and) are at odds with both the results when using either of the other two methods, AND different to the results when using method 1 on any other label.

Thanks a ton for your patient kind help, this must be one of the most basic questions.

Running Python 3.4 on Anaconda 2.1 w pandas 0.14.1

---

The problem can be reproduced with:

```
import pandas as pd
belly = '216 3T19'.split()
wing1 = '2T15 4H19'.split()
wing2 = '416 4T20'.split()
mat = pd.to_datetime('2016-01-22 2019-09-07'.split())

tbondfly = pd.DataFrame({'wing1':wing1, 'wing2':wing2, 'mat':mat}, index=belly)
#             mat wing1 wing2
# 216  2016-01-22  2T15   416
# 3T19 2019-09-07  4H19  4T20
```

Comment: Can you provide sample code to generate a DataFrame showing this behavior?

Comment: This might actually be a good question for the pandas mailing list, as some of the primary developers will be familiar enough with the nuance to give you a better answer.

Comment: do this on >= 0.15.0; a couple of bugs in .loc with this kind of selection in 0.14.1

Comment: could be as well, he is that issue: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9477

Comment: this should fix these issues: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/9501